# Managing ticks for multiple lines on the same subplot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot multiple lines in the same plot, like in the picture below:
[image]
The problem with the picture is that if the Y values of the graphs aren't similar the y ticks get jumbled, it's unclear which tick is related to the first graph and which one isn't.

Is there a way for me to colour the ticks of each graph differently (preferably to the colour of the graph)? or maybe separate it into different columns?

Also, I wouldn't mind using more than one subplot, as long as the graphs' space overlaps.

The code I use to create the new lines:

```py
def generate_graph():
    colors = "rgbmcmyk"
    subplot_recent.clear()
    lines_drawn = []
    mat_figure.legends = []
    for i in range(n):
        lines_drawn.append(["A Name", subplot_recent.plot(values[i][0], values[i][1], colors[i])[0]])
    mat_figure.legend((i[1] for i in lines_drawn), (i[0] for i in lines_drawn), 'upper right')
    subplot_recent.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(10))
    mat_canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: How about creating a second y-axis on the right side? You can use [`twinx()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.twinx.html) for this and treat it as a separate axis, which shares the x-axis with the underlying axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error actually was that I forgot to cast the values to int/float, and so matplotlib didn't really know what to do with them all to well.
It's fixed now. Thanks!